# American kitchen towel. I've seen lots of interesting stuff on here, but What is it in a recipe?

Tags: vocabulary

My recipe for bottling (Am.canning) sour cherries tells me to put 
old kitchen towels in the base of a water bath. I'll be standing glass jars on them, and boiling the whole shebang.  Sooo - am I supposed to use something like a J-cloth or something like a tea towel? I'm pretty sure I'm not to use British kitchen towel aka kitchen paper. 
Could someone who cooks answer, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask this on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (the SE subsite devoted to cookery). But *maybe* Americans usually understand "kitchen towels" as equivalent to "kitchen **cloths** / tea towels", I dunno.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for cooking/bottling advice.

Comment: So are you using British terminology? Is 'kitchen towel' for you made out of paper or cloth? Whatever things are called, I think using paper in boiling water is probably not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Mari-Lou A - you are mistaken. The bottling thing was merely an example. Also, my terminology though British now is skewed by being originally Australian, which is more profoundly influenced by American forms.

Answer (score 2):

An American *kitchen towel* is indeed something like a tea towel.

It is simply a (cloth) towel used in the kitchen. These days, kitchen towels are often made of terry cloth, whereas tea towels - at least, what Americans call tea towels - are typically flat woven fabric.

In the US, kitchen towels are sometimes called *dish towels*, or *dish cloths*. This page on the Williams Sonoma website (an American kitchenware store) uses the terms interchangeably:

> #### Refresh Your Kitchen Towels
>
> Indulge in the satisfaction of all new *kitchen towels*...The well-stocked kitchen has lots of *dish towels* at hand throughout the room...*Dish cloths* make serving meals infinitely easier. Mitts or potholders keep your hands safe and cool while you reach into the oven or grab a pot off a burner, but *dish towels* enter the picture as vital kitchen support when things are really cooking. Use *kitchen towels* as extra trivets or big mats to place hot items while cooking...

https://www.williams-sonoma.com/shop/homekeeping/dish-cloths-towels/ (emphasis added throughout)

On the other hand, another American kitchenware company, Sur La Table, seems to think that dish cloths are smaller than kitchen towels and they're mostly square, whereas kitchen towels are rectangular.

https://www.surlatable.com/category/TCA-257921/Kitchen+Towels+%26+Dishcloths

In any case, a kitchen towel is definitely made of cloth, not paper.  If it were made of paper we would call it a *paper towel*.

Comment: So that's what the markup on W-S merchandise goes to—their SEO consultants.